# Gap between two <div> tags with display:inline-block

Tags: html

So, I'm using `display:inline-block` to put 2 `<div>` tags side by side in HTML. They have no margin and no padding.

Still there appears to be a gap between the two `<div>` tags.

My question is why is there a gap in the first place. Shouldn't the `<div>`s be flush next to each other? Is this an artifact of the spec or not? This happens across browsers. (tested on IE and Chrome)

Here's an image
[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/v60e8wm5/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the display short of inline, there is space between them as `<b>Hello,</b> World` have space between them.

Because there is space between the tags

```
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
```

Test with

```
<div>Test</div><div>Test</div>
```

or

```
<div>Test</div><!--
--><div>Test</div>
```

Comment: Correct. My Bad. Somehow this slipped my mind as a possibility. Feeling stupid

Comment: Not really, this is very annoying also it should behave this way, i know...